# Extjs - How to get displayfields from itemselector?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

The Extjs Itemselector component has methods like getValue, getSubmitData, getSubmitValue which will return the keys of the records that are selected.

I am looking for a better way than taking the keys of the records selected from the component and fetching for the record from the store by searching the store in a sequential fashion. This is a very time expensive solution which is not working well for me since the itemselector has a large number of records.

Question : is there a way to retrieve the displayed string/value (in the selected part of the itemselector) along with the keys directly from the component and not as above ?

thanks
Nohsib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works in my code to get an array of all the records which you can then get the values from, it may not work in yours if you have a different version of Extjs:

```
itemSelectorField.toField.store.getRange();
```

Oh and if you want the display values as a string list:

```
itemSelectorField.toField.store.getRange().collect("display_value_propery_name").join(",");
```

Comment: itemSelectorField.toField.store.getRange(); worked for me. Thanks Reimius